# Is there a way to search or creates notes for technical issues in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

Assume I come across a technical issue and have resolved the same. Now, I just wanted to let everyone knows the issue as well as the solution. In this way we can keep the technical queries in tact at one place before any person answers the question.

1. Place to put the issue and solution
2. Reviews
3. Possible additional solutions can be added

Please let me know.

Comment: You can self-answer your question, but the question needs to conform to SO's normal rules (and of course, everyone else can contribute an answer, too). Can you make an example of such an issue and its solution?